# How to escape [ and % characters in TT2

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I am using [TT2](http://template-toolkit.org/). I want to print `something[%0d]` from my template file. But i cannot seem to find any escape character for template toolkit usage.

Any suggestions as to how to skip `%` and `[` to be processed under `TT`?

The exact line is:

```
printer.print_object(.name($sformatf("[% item %]_slv_agent_cfg[%0d]:", i)), .value([% item %]_slv_agent_cfg[i]));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::FAQ#If-Im-using-TT-to-write-out-a-TT-template-is-there-a-good-way-to-escape-and

Comment: @melpomene: Please enhance that and submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
[% "[%" %]
```

in lieu of

```
[%
```

It would look like this:

```
$ tpage <<<'slv_agent_cfg[% "[%" %]0d]'
slv_agent_cfg[%0d]
```

```
$ tpage <<<'slv_agent_cfg[% "[%0d]" %]'
slv_agent_cfg[%0d]
```

---

A shorter solution would be to use

```
[[%%]%
```

in lieu of

```
[%
```

It would look like this:

```
$ tpage <<<'slv_agent_cfg[[%%]%0d]'
slv_agent_cfg[%0d]
```

---

If you find yourself needing to escape too many instances, you could switch the [tag style](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template::Manual::Config#TAG_STYLE).

---

Finally, you could alter the program to avoid the sequence in the first place. For example, you might be able to replace

```
"slv_agent_cfg[%0d]"
```

with

```
"slv_agent_cfg[\%0d]"
```

or

```
{"slv_agent_cfg[","%0d]"}
```

I don't know Verilog, so the specifics may not be correct, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

[If I'm using TT to write out a TT template, is there a good way to escape [% and %]?](http://search.cpan.org/~abw/Template-Toolkit-2.25/lib/Template/FAQ.pod#If_I%27m_using_TT_to_write_out_a_TT_template,_is_there_a_good_way_to_escape_[%25_and_%25]?)

So `something[\%0d]` should work.

Comment: That's not actually what your link says.

Comment: Yes, you're right - a bit too hasty posting. Will remove.

Comment: Undeleted in response to Borodin's comment on the OP.